# Power bi: Restrict data in a chart using dax

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax

I have a chart where in X-axis, its the day of the quarter, in y-axis is the amount. in legend is the year and Quarter.
This is the backlog data for that reason it have the future data too.
In the X-axis, The days will be constant i.e., 92 (Maximum number of days in a quarter)
Today is Jan 8th,2024, 8th day of the quarter, so the data needs to be showed until 8(the chart should not show any data from 9 to 92. similar to QTD) even when 9 or 10 have the data. How to restrict this using a dax formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared any info on your data model set-up and what you are using for the Y-axis. The following may work for you:

```
Chart Y-axis value = 
  TOTALQTD(
    SUM('table'[something]),
    'YourDateTable'[Date],
    'YourDateTable'[Date] <= TODAY()
  )
```

Or alternatively:

```
Chart Y-axis value = 
  var todayQtrDay = DATEDIFF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), (QUARTER(TODAY()) - 1) * 3 + 1, 1), TODAY(), DAY) + 1
  var chartX = SELECTEDVALUE('Same as your X-axis'[Day])
  var result = <your calculation>
  return IF(chartX <= todayQtrDay, result)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! The alternative result worked prefectly